# cv.undistort "Assertion failed" error in Javascript

Tags: javascript, opencv

I am trying to undistort an image with opencv.js before scanning aruco markers with my camera.
Scanning the codes is not a problem but when i try to undistort the image first with cv.undistort i run into an Assertion failed error which looks something like [this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wnn7T.png)

Minimal working example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script id="cv" async src="opencv.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <canvas id="canvasOutput" width="640" height="480"></canvas>
</body>

<script>

  document.getElementById('cv').addEventListener('load', async () => {
    if (cv.getBuildInformation) {
      console.log(cv.getBuildInformation());
      onloadCallback();
    }
    else {
      // WASM
      if (cv instanceof Promise) {
        cv = await cv;
        console.log(cv.getBuildInformation());
        onloadCallback();
      } else {
        cv['onRuntimeInitialized'] = () => {
          console.log(cv.getBuildInformation());
          onloadCallback();
        }
      }
    }
  });

  function onloadCallback() {

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvasOutput')
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d", { willReadFrequently: true });
    var video_element = document.createElement("video")
    video_element.id = "video-stream"
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
    video: {}}).then(function (stream) {
     video_element.srcObject = stream;
     video_element.play();
     video_element.addEventListener('canplay', function () {
        requestAnimationFrame(() => {processImage()});
      }, false);
    });

    function processImage() {
      if (video_element.readyState === video_element.HAVE_ENOUGH_DATA) {
        
        ctx.drawImage(video_element, 0, 0, canvas.width,canvas.height);
        var inputImage = cv.imread("canvasOutput"); 

        var cameraMatrix = cv.matFromArray(3, 3, cv.CV_64F, [740.50225182, 0, 369.29446792, 0, 740.73074392, 252.55216544, 0, 0, 1]);
        var newCameraMatrix = cv.matFromArray(3, 3, cv.CV_64F, [719.72668457, 0, 374.17970017, 0, 711.57000732, 251.96928564, 0, 0, 1]);
        var distCoeffs = cv.matFromArray(1, 5, cv.CV_64F, [0.0798354, -0.55563903, -0.00168822, 0.00225224, 0.28264803]);
        cv.cvtColor(inputImage, inputImage, cv.COLOR_RGBA2RGB, 0);
        
        var markerIds = new cv.Mat();
        var markerCorners = new cv.MatVector();
        var rvecs = new cv.Mat();
        var tvecs = new cv.Mat();
        var dictionary = new cv.Dictionary(cv.DICT_6X6_1000);

        cv.undistort(inputImage,cameraMatrix,distCoeffs,newCameraMatrix);
        cv.detectMarkers(inputImage,dictionary, markerCorners, markerIds);

        if (markerIds.rows > 0) {
          cv.drawDetectedMarkers(inputImage,markerCorners,markerIds);
          cv.estimatePoseSingleMarkers(markerCorners, 0.1, cameraMatrix,distCoeffs,rvecs,tvecs);
          for (let i = 0; i < markerIds.rows; ++i) {
           rvec = cv.matFromArray(3, 1, cv.CV_64F, [rvecs.doublePtr(0, i)[0],rvecs.doublePtr(0, i)[1],rvecs.doublePtr(0, i)[2]]);
           tvec = cv.matFromArray(3, 1, cv.CV_64F, [tvecs.doublePtr(0, i)[0],tvecs.doublePtr(0, i)[1],tvecs.doublePtr(0, i)[2]]);
           cv.drawAxis(inputImage,cameraMatrix,distCoeffs,rvec, tvec, 0.1);
           rvec.delete();
           tvec.delete();
          }
        }
        cv.imshow("canvasOutput",inputImage);

        inputImage.delete();
        dictionary.delete();
        markerIds.delete();
        markerCorners.delete();
        rvecs.delete();
        tvecs.delete();
        cameraMatrix.delete();
        newCameraMatrix.delete();
        distCoeffs.delete();
      }
      requestAnimationFrame(() => {processImage()});
    }
  }

</script>


</html>
```

where the opencv.js file in the head can be any OpenCV js version (example https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/opencv.js)

I have no idea what this means and i'm not sure how to make it work.

I think I defined the size of the camera matrix correctly as well as the sizes of all other parameters but I just keep getting the same error.

When I try to do this in python everything works fine. I can't seem to figure out what I'm doing wrong when I try to replicate this in javascript.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the `cv.undistort` method didn't have proper parameters passed to it, more specificaly it was called with 4 parameters instead of 5 and it didn't have the output parameter defined:

```
cv.undistort(inputImage,cameraMatrix,distCoeffs,newCameraMatrix);
```

should be

```
var output = new cv.Mat();
cv.undistort(inputImage, output,cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, newCameraMatrix );
```